# LinearLayout analog inside Table in LibGDX

Tags: android, layout, libgdx, scene2d

I want to create a game menu screen in LibGDX using scene2d package with following layout

```
|    label    |
| btn btn btn |
|    label    |
```

My code looks as follows:

```
Table table = getTable();
table.add(label1);
table.row();
table.add(button1);
table.add(button2);
table.add(button3);
table.row();
table.add(label2);
table.row();
```

But instead of what I want I get something like this:

```
| label       |
| btn btn btn |
| label       |
```

The reason is because each `table.add()` method call creates a new one cell. But I want to place all my 3 buttons inside one cell. How can I achieve desired result, may be in LibGDX existing something like `LinearLayout` or whatever else?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Call  `colspan(3)` on the cell that is returned to you when calling `add(label);`

ex.

```
Cell cell = table.add(label1);
cell.colspan(3);
```

This, as the name implies, sets how many columns the cell will span across.
You may need to set the alignment on the cell also by calling `cell.center();`

you can string together these calls since they all return the same cell object..

```
table.add(label1).colspan(3).center();
```

The Cell class doesn't seem documented for libgdx.. I simply went on the source code found [here](http://gazbot-decal.googlecode.com/git-history/e8881262d18232b900a2de6a088a0a879f103a70/gdx-shared-libs/libs/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/ui/tablelayout/Cell.html)

The cell class documentation can be found [here](http://gazbot-decal.googlecode.com/git-history/e8881262d18232b900a2de6a088a0a879f103a70/gdx-shared-libs/libs/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/ui/tablelayout/Cell.html) for now. It does seem to be missing from the official docs.